# Conditional probability - probability of event once a certain event has been reached.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A juggler practices juggling. His results vary quite a bit. Sometimes he drops the balls quickly, sometimes he can hang in there for a while.
Here is a distribution of his juggling durations after 36 attempts:

| Duration (s) | No of attempts |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 9 |
| 10 | 9 |
| 15 | 6 |
| 20 | 5 |
| 25 | 3 |
| 30 | 4 |

The question is: how likely is he going to continue past a certain duration once he reaches it?

My idea would be e.g. for 5 seconds:
He stops after 5 seconds 9 times, but he achieves > 5 seconds 36-9=27 times
Hence his likelihood of reaching more than 5 seconds once he is at the 5 s mark is 1-(9/27) =66%

Or, once he reaches 10 seconds:
9 times he reaches 10 seconds (attempts to 5 dont count because they dont reach 10 seconds), 18 times he goes past 10, so the likelihood of passing 10s once reached is 50% or:p= 1-(9/18).

Is this right?

Comment: I agree with your approach, but I think the attempts where he drops it at the given time should also be included in the denominator. So the first should be $\frac{27}{36} = \frac34.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: The table gives the frequency of *stopping* at each duration.

However, you seek the *conditional* probability for *continuing* when given that a duration is reached.

---

This uses Bayes' Rule. When $X$ is the duration, then $\{X>a\}$ is the event of exceeding duration $a$, and $\{X\geq a\}$ is the event of reaching duration $a$. So the probability we seek is:
$$\mathsf P(X>a\mid X\geq a)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X > a)}{\mathsf P(X\geq a)}$$

Thusly the probability for exceeding $10$s when given that *at least* $10$s has been reached is:  $$\mathsf P(X> 10\mid X\geq 10)=\dfrac{~~~~~~~6+5+3+4}{9+6+5+3+4}=\dfrac{18}{27}$$

Comment: And for 5s: (9+6+5+3+4)/(9+9+6+5+3+4)?

Comment: 15s: (5+3+4)/(6+5+3+4)? just to be sure I got it

Comment: Yes, that is so.